# Spring boot -Axon framework NoHandlerForCommandException: No Handler for command

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I am getting NoHandlerForCommandException: No Handler for command while trying to use Axon framework with Spring boot.

Below are my Java files :

The Rest controller ->

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private CommandGateway gateway;

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity createProduct(@RequestBody CreateProductModel model) {
    
    CreateProductCommand command=CreateProductCommand.builder()
            .price("$123")
            .productId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .product("Shoe")
            .build();
    
    String s=gateway.sendAndWait(command);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

The ProductCreatedEvent object ->

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ProductCreatedEvent {
@TargetAggregateIdentifier
private  String productId;
private  String product;
private  String price ;
```

}

The command class CreateProductCommand ->

```
@Builder
@Data
public class CreateProductCommand {
@TargetAggregateIdentifier
private final String productId;
private final String product;
private final String price ;
```

}

The Aggregate class ->

```
@Aggregate
public class ProductAggregate {

@AggregateIdentifier
private  String productId;
private  String product;
private  String price ;

public ProductAggregate() {
    
}

@CommandHandler
public ProductAggregate(CreateProductCommand command) {
    //TODO: Validation logic can be handled here
    ProductCreatedEvent event=new ProductCreatedEvent();
    
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(command, event);
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(event);
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(ProductCreatedEvent event) {
    this.price=event.getPrice();
    this.productId=event.getProductId();
    this.product=event.getProduct();
    
}

}
```

Comment: What are the package names of these classes? What package is your SpringBoot Application class in

Comment: All these classes are in diffenet packages..even the spring boot application is in a different package.Is it required to keep all these classes in same package?

Comment: It's not required but that influences where Spring will check for classes to register `Bean`s used by Axon later on. If you can provide the packages of your classes (just edit the question including them), also the SpringBoot Application one, that would help. Added, if you can also provide the `application.properties` (if you have configured something on that), it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the annotation TargetAggregateIdentifier
in The ProductCreatedEvent class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).